# Shipping MySQL Database with android app

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have created an app which needs a local database.
i have made the database using MYSQL.
How to connect the database to the app

Comment: bu default local data base is available SQlite. So use this sqlite database.

Comment: @sunil, this is not by default, it's the only option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not connect MySQL database to android application on the device (I have heard of very few solutions that require installing additional software or device rooting). The only option you have is SQLite - this is natively supported by the DB API of the Android SDK.

EDIT: [Here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1wTc3UjuktHCgqEJijyg6JRcvX-VizYMTt33smf--yXA/edit) is a presentation I have prepared regarding databases in Android and [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdg-sofia-prototypes/source/browse/#svn/trunk/AndroidPersistenceBenchmark) is a prototype application that demonstrates them (it includes example of shipping database with the application)